# Trigger file download by pure javascript

Tags: javascript, http, download, mime

There will be **no server side request**. So it has to be done by pure JS. For example I have this code.

```
function downloadFile(data, name, mime){
    /// what to put here?
}
var txt="Hello world";
var filename="sample.txt";
var mime="text/plain";
downloadFile(txt,filename, mime);
```

I know of [a library](http://jspdf.com/) that does it  entirely in browser without sending any http request. 
If I send a request I can do it by server side script. Just get the data and with some header a file download can be triggered. But I want to do it in Pure JS. NO server-side request.

Comment: What about using a data URL? Does it need to work in IE8?

Comment: Have you tried looking at how the library does that?

Comment: @Jan I have a lot of things on [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). I think I got my answer

Comment: What do you mean by "no server side request". Does it mean that you don't want to make any request to the server?
Also if you have found the answer, it would be better to share it with others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library you linked to uses https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify/ which uses Flash to ensure cross-browser compatibility. If you don't need to be sure that it works in all browsers, you can use a data uri and a pure javascript implementation as demonstrated here: https://gist.github.com/syntagmatic/2202660. You could also look at the new HTML5 File API: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/#toc-filesystemurls.

Comment: If flash isn't installed or not allowed to run then Downloadify will also fall.
The HTML5 File Api only works with Chrome and is therefore no option for cross-browser solution.
Also data-uris as used in the pure javascript implementation you've mentioned doesn't work in "the best browser ever IE". Why isn't that wondering me. The IE is a pain in the ass since it was developed but because it is default onboard in the most windows versions it is used widely. In IE you have to use blob urls. For that you can use btoa.